# How to use operators?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program to prompt the user for hours and rate per hour to compute gross pay:

```
hours = input('Enter the hours you worked = ')
rate = input('Enter the rate = ')
pay = hours*rate
print(pay)
```

I am getting an error:

File "Hello", line 3, in 
    pay = hours*rate
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Comment: You need to convert str into int.

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = input('Enter the hours you worked = ')
rate = input('Enter the rate = ')
pay = int(hours)* int(rate)
print(pay)
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```py
hours = int(input('Enter the hours you worked = '))
rate = int(input('Enter the rate = '))
pay = hours*rate
print(pay)
```

see [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)